# Mac Mini M1 with three monitors

Tags: mac, display, mac-mini

As you know the Mac Mini M1 has one HDMI, 2 USB-C connectors.  Currently I connected two monitors to it via the HDMI and through one of the USB-C port.

So what happens if I connect another monitor to the 2nd USB-C port?  Will it provide me a third display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The M1 chips support a total of two monitors. For the Mac Mini, that means two external monitors. For the MacBook Air and MacBook Pro (M1, not M1 Pro or Max), that means the internal monitor and one external monitor.

You can use a DisplayLink USB Virtual Graphics Card to use more external displays. Note however that this requires a driver installation that may break when macOS updates, and it doesn't use the M1's native graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

As documented, the Mac mini M1 supports two external monitors.

https://www.apple.com/mac-mini/specs/

Answer (score 0):

My simple workaround with the tools I had available:

1 Monitor via HDMI
1 Monitor via USB-C to HDMI
1 Monitor via Airplay to Apple TV

I had a spare apple tv I wasn't using so I gave it a go. Note it is a fresh desktop and NOT mirrored, unlike many posts were suggesting.

I do know there are other more optimal solution but I'd be willing to bet more people have a apple tv laying out than hub/splitter/etc.

Hope that helps those in a pinch.